# when install the festival tts does not work make command

Tags: text-to-speech, festival

I am trying to create a new voice for my final year project in university. Hence I am using Festival tts and festvox but when i install festival an error coming. it shows flowing image. how can i resolve

[image] this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of festival probably has no default voice set. You can do

```
    sudo apt-get install festvox-rablpc16k
```

And set the default voice as in festival console

```
    (set! default_voice 'voice_rab_diphone)
```

You can find more details in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=677277

Comment: I was trying to develop a new voice in my language. i read several research papers and tried to do that with the aid of some articles. i tried more than 15 times. every time i failed. so you know how to do this voice creation. please help me to get some step to forward

Comment: There are different types of voices you can build in festival. You could build a diphone-based voice (http://www.festvox.org/bsv/c3583.html), unit selection voice (http://www.festvox.org/festvox/x3086.html) or limited domain voices (http://tts.speech.cs.cmu.edu/11-823/hints/clock.html). You will need a set of phones and recordings for your language for building voice in your language.

Comment: thank you for your consideration. But First two links are not working. i can not reach those links